# man diff does not correspond to the diff version installed

Tags: macos, unix, manpage

executing `man diff` tells the following:

```
NAME
       diff - compare files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       diff [OPTION]... FILES

DESCRIPTION
       Compare files line by line.

       -i  --ignore-case
              Ignore case differences in file contents.

[...]
       -q  --brief
              Output only whether files differ.
[...]
```

but when I use the `-q` option, it fails with `fatal: invalid diff option/value: -q`

Why does the man of the diff command do not correspond to the version installed?

How to fix it?

Is there a brew package who has a version of the diff command with the `-q` option?
(brew coreutils and binutils do not have the diff command)

OSX 10.11.5

**Update with your questions**

```
$ which diff
/usr/bin/diff

$ diff --version
usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>

$ diff -v
usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>

$ command diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
```

I use brew and https://github.com/donnemartin/dev-setup

If I disable the `.bash_profile` installed by dev-setup, then `which diff` still returns the same path but `diff -q` works.

Comment: What is the output of `which diff`?

Comment: Question has been put on hold so I can't post an answer, but your `.bash_profile` sources `.functions`, and `.functions` does `function diff() { git diff --no-index --color-words "$@";  } `. `git diff` differs slightly from  `diff`.

Comment: I see, it is using git diff. i didn't think that it could be a problem with git diff because i thought that it would only work on files from a git repository. good catch, thx. is there something i can do so that you can post an answer and i can reward yours?

Comment: It's OK. Maybe @DimP's answer can be edited to mention that `dev-setup` is another piece of software that changes the user's diff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you, by any chance, use anything like [pretzo](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) or something similar? Some frameworks like this will (badly) define their own functions replacing the terminal default ones.

In that case, try running `command diff -q ...` and see if this resolves the issue.

**Edit**: As @MarkPlotnick pointed out, [dev-setup](http://github.com/donnemartin/dev-setup) is another framework that overrides the default `diff` command and uses `git diff` instead:

```
# Use Git’s colored diff when available
hash git &>/dev/null;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    function diff() {
        git diff --no-index --color-words "$@";
    }
fi;
```

**Reference**: https://github.com/donnemartin/dev-setup/blob/master/.functions

Comment: So does the `-q` option work in this way?

Comment: yes; as Mark Plotnick said in a comment to my question, it was https://github.com/donnemartin/dev-setup who redefined diff.